# How I gonna choose Pets type if the first drop down menu user only choose favourite colour blue or red?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my code. If user choose favourite colour either red or blue, how gonna user choose their pets type? The drop down menu for pet type and submit button did not appear if user select favourite colour red or blue. Kindly I dont have basic Javascript.

```js
function checkchange() {
  if (document.getElementById('favouritecolour').value == 'OTHERS') {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
  }
};

function check() {
  if (document.getElementById('pets').value == 'OTHERS') {
    document.getElementById('besides').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('besides').style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```html
<label for="favouritecolour">Favourite colour</label>
<select id='favouritecolour' onChange='checkchange()'>
  <option value='BLUE'>BLUE</option>
  <option value='RED'>RED</option>
  <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='other' style="display: none">
  <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN" />
  <br/>
  <label for="pets">Pets do you like</label>
  <select id='pets' onChange='check()'>
    <option value='DOG'>DOG</option>
    <option value='RABBIT'>RABBIT</option>
    <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
  </select>
  <div id='besides' style="display: none">
    <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN" />
    <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont understand u logic. i change a blue. so what? what i see?

Comment: you can submit or not? and you can choose pets type or not after you select the blue or red. Besides others, the second field and submit button will appear

Answer (score 0):

1) You misspelled method name: `onChange` should be replaced with `onchange` ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp))

2) There are some problems with elements nesting (for example, Your div `other` including not only input, but some other elements), try this HTML:

```
<label for="favouritecolour">Favourite colour</label>
<select id='favouritecolour' onchange='checkchange()'>
  <option value='BLUE'>BLUE</option>
  <option value='RED'>RED</option>
  <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='other' style="display: none">
  <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN" />
</div>
<br/>
<label for="pets">Pets do you like</label>
<select id='pets' onchange='check()'>
  <option value='DOG'>DOG</option>
  <option value='RABBIT'>RABBIT</option>
  <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='besides' style="display: none">
  <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN" />
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
```

Comment: hmmm...nothing changes.

Comment: nope. hmm.. you already run the code? If you select the favourite colour blue or red, the second drop down not appear. The second drop down will appear, when user select OTHER from favourite colour

Comment: Looks like You reversed the condition in Your `checkchange` method: you set display to `block` (i.e. shows the button etc) if user selects `OTHERS` value. If You wants to show it when user selects anything but `OTHERS`, You should replace condition from `==` to `!=`

Comment: But. If user already choose the blue colour, why must insert another value? Only for Other can insert another value

Comment: which one?can you mention it?

Comment: Edit in my answer, I posted there whole HTML, try to use it.

Comment: Already bro! Thank you. Mistake at the div tag. Really-really helpful. Thank you so much for your help! Proud of you